# All ADB devices offline when starting adb at boot

Tags: android, linux, service, raspberry-pi, adb

I'm testing an application which records user travels for later review. One part of testing involves testing application behavior when under user specified battery level.

It must stop recording to save battery. I have built a system with a raspberry pi that when you flip a switch, `adb` commands are sent to all connected devices to mock battery status.

My issue is when I tried to have `adb` as startup or as a service it, `adb` list all device offline thus the device doesn't work. My script will work as long you start manually the `adb` server.

**More info:**

It is the cold season here so we use a car to record travels. We can't have a screen on the device to comply with local regulations that is why, I require the `adb` to start at boot or during account automatic login.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Can you explain  in more detail how are you starting `adb` and how devices are connected?

Comment: The raspberry pi is running Ubuntu mate. I tried starting adb with rc.local, as a service with update-rc.d , using ubuntu startup application UI and through my script. The devices are connected via usb.

Comment: was `adb` installed from official google download? I've seen some problems when some packages are used. Does it work from command line?

Comment: No it was installed from debian repo. I am unsure how to build adb for arm7.

Comment: Isolate the problem. Does `adb` work from command line but not when started as a service?

Comment: Yes it work as long as it is started by the user.